# How to add dropdown to 'view/title' with VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

[image]

Is it possible to add a dropdown (Run extension) like in the screenshot above?

Comment: the View API for VSC internally is much more elaborate than what is available to extensions, one option is to create a WebviewView and put the combo box inside this WebviewView

Comment: is it possible to inject treeview to webview? i would like to keep it together rather than split to groups

Comment: You have to completely implement what you want in the WebviewView. There may be Web GUI's that have a tree implemented, I have used Svelte in a WebviewView.